# VirtualMachine crashes after start

Tags: virtualbox

After reinstalling Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.10 and trying to start a virtual machine getting the following

```
    Failed to open a session for the virtual machine trial.

The virtual machine 'trial' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with
     exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

$ dkms status

gives

```
 bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-304, 304.135, 4.8.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-304, 304.135, 4.8.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.1.6, 4.8.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff 
between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) 
(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Can it be connected ?

Virtualbox suggests i try

```
 $ modprobe vboxdrv
```

but it gives no effect.

What can be done to make it work?

```
$ dpkg -l virtualbox*
```

gives

```
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|
    / Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
    ||/ Name                      Version           Architecture    Description
    +++-=========================-=================-=================-========================================================
ii  virtualbox                5.1.6-dfsg-2      amd64             x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
un  virtualbox-2.0            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.1            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.2            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.0            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.1            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.2            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.0            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.1            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.2            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.3            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.0            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-5.1:i386       5.1.26-117224~Ubu i386              Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms           5.1.6-dfsg-2      all               x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for 
un  virtualbox-guest-addition <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-modules  <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-x11      <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-modules        <none>            <none>            (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose            <none>            <none>            (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-qt             5.1.6-dfsg-2      amd64             x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
un  virtualbox-source         <none>            <none>            (no description available)
```

It was installed via

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox

$ sudo dpkg -s virtualbox
```

gives

```
Package: virtualbox
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/misc
Installed-Size: 70997
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 5.1.6-dfsg-2
Depends: adduser, procps, virtualbox-dkms (>= 5.1.6-dfsg-2) | virtualbox-source (>= 5.1.6-dfsg-2) | virtualbox-modules, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), python2.7, python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), libc6 (>= 2.15), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgsoap9, libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10), libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxmu6, libxt6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 5.1.6-dfsg-2), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta), libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5opengl5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2)
Suggests: vde2, virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Conflicts: virtualbox-2.0, virtualbox-2.1, virtualbox-2.2, virtualbox-3.0, virtualbox-3.1, virtualbox-3.2, virtualbox-4.0, virtualbox-4.1, virtualbox-4.2, virtualbox-4.3, virtualbox-5.0, virtualbox-5.1
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/virtualbox 903beafa3922607d1ac07950d9ae2d50
 /etc/init.d/virtualbox 3aed81b34e30eca2393ca3c9730da675
Description: x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
 VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
 of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on a
 Linux system.
 .
 This package provides the binaries for VirtualBox. Either the virtualbox-dkms
 or the virtualbox-source package is also required in order to compile the
 kernel modules needed for virtualbox. A graphical user interface for
 VirtualBox is provided by the package virtualbox-qt.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Virtualbox Team <pkg-virtualbox-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: http://www.virtualbox.org/

$ sudo dpkg -s virtualbox-5.1
```

gives

```
Package: virtualbox-5.1
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/misc
Installed-Size: 158172
Maintainer: Oracle Corporation <info@virtualbox.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~yakkety
Config-Version: 5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~yakkety
Replaces: virtualbox
Provides: virtualbox
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0), libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5opengl5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.6.0~beta), libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0), libx11-6, libxcb1, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxinerama1, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxmu6, libxt6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), psmisc, adduser
Pre-Depends: debconf (>= 1.1) | debconf-2.0
Recommends: libasound2, libpulse0, libsdl-ttf2.0-0, kmod | kldutils | module-init-tools, linux-headers-generic | linux-headers-generic-pae | linux-headers-686-pae | linux-headers-amd64 | linux-headers-2.6-686 | linux-headers-2.6-amd64 | linux-headers, linux-image, gcc, make | build-essential | dpkg-dev, binutils, pdf-viewer, libgl1
Conflicts: virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions-iso, virtualbox-ose
Description: Oracle VM VirtualBox
 VirtualBox is a powerful PC virtualization solution allowing you to run a
 wide range of PC operating systems on your Linux system. This includes
 Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, DOS, OpenBSD and others. VirtualBox comes with a broad
 feature set and excellent performance, making it the premier virtualization
 software solution on the market.
Python-Version: 2.7
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65493/discussion-on-question-by-mikhail-yudaev-virtualmachine-crashes-after-start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is here (there may be more):

**dkms status shows...**

```
virtualbox, 5.1.6, 4.8.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Sometimes this error can be difficult to fix.

**This dkms kernel driver has a problem...**

```
ii  virtualbox-dkms           5.1.6-dfsg-2      all               x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for
```

**First try at an easy fix...**

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms # uninstall it
sudo apt-get update # update the software database
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms # reinstall it
dkms status # check the status
```

Look to see if the "WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!" is gone. If not, we'll have to try again, the hard way.

**Note:** If guest OS "Trial" is the only one that fails, and other guest OS's run ok, then there may be a corrupt snapshot file for guest OS "Trial".

**Another option... probably easier...**

Uninstall the 5.1.6 version that you have, and install version 5.1.26.

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

Comment: @OrganicMarble was your comment intended for the original question/OP? ps: un means uninstalled. Also, a better dpkg command would be `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`.

Comment: Tried easy fix... The warning message remains the same. I tried to start the virtual machine with 3 different live CDs - all gave the same error.

Comment: It looks as if the second variant worked. At least now it boots Mint Liza successfully and deadlocks while trying to boot with Peppermint - don't know why. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @MikhailYudaev Are you using Mint or Ubuntu as your host OS?  (Or, is Mint the guest OS?)  I ask because we don't support Mint here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasWard Looks like Ubuntu... "reinstalling Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.10". Mint and Peppermint are guest OS's.